# standalone with floats/figures

Tags: floats, standalone

I'm writing a small tool that takes figures/tables etc out of LaTeX code and compiles them as a [standalone](https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone?lang=en) PDF. It works mostly fine, but I have problems with [subfig](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfig?lang=en) since it needs a `figure` environment. The following fails to compile:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[Some title.]{abc}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

```
error: a.tex:8: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

It works with `\documentclass{article}`. It also compiles with `\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}`, but that cuts off the content:

[image]

Is there a way to make standalone work with figures?

Comment: Why would you add the caption into the image in the first place? Then the caption font and the font of the document the image is inserted into are not the same.

Comment: @daleif I don't care too much about fonts, but about the content of the caption. I cannot omit it.

Comment: `standalone` package is not intended to contain floats. If you persist to have it, than you should try the following: `\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{6em}
\centering
    abc
\caption{Some title.}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}`

Comment: Also, all the captions would have the same number or letter.  You would need `\setcounter{figure}{...}` with the appropriate value (not sure what the counter name is for subfig).

Comment: If you're taking the figures and tables out and doing the same with them, what do you do in those cases?

Answer (score 1):

This will run without errors.  Note the (b) subcaption.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{subfig}

\makeatletter
\def\@captype{figure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{subfigure}{1}
\subfloat[Some title.]{abc}
\end{document}
```